# Campo que filtre en horas minutos o segundos

Tags: python, django, django-models

me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una especie de timefield en el que se mostrara un campo para poner un numero junto a un desplegable que contenga segundos, minutos y horas, pudiendo decidir tú que quieres añadir.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo la [pagina oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/) donde puedes encontrar todos los tipos de inputs que hay.

Para hacer lo que quieres es bien sencillo una vez que lees la documentación, pero igual te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.db.models import Model 
  
class TimeModel(Model):
    field_name = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options)
```

Comment: Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta con el código que probaste y el error que te da.